# Facebook deleting post

Tags: javascript, facebook, fb.ui

I'm using Faceebok JS API, function FB.ui to post. But whenever I click on post it with no text, the post is deleted seconds after I posted. When I enter a text, it doesn't get deleted. My function is:

```
function postar(){
          FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'x',
    link: 'x',
    picture: 'x',
    caption: 'x',
    description: 'x'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      console.log('Post was published.');
    } else {
      console.log('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

does anybody know how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wild guess, enter text in your posts ?

Comment: This is by design, there is no point to having a non-text/content post. As a workaround, try using a blank space?